# Java eclipse jakarta importing packages error compilation message

Tags: java, eclipse, backend

I am creating a servlet in a dynamic web project in Java Enterprise Edition of Eclipse ide. But when I try to import the jakarta packages, it throws an error saying **" The import jakarta.servlet cannot be resolved "**
I am really confused.
Can you please help me out.

**Here are the codes for my servlet**

```
package studentReg2.allforStudent;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;


@WebServlet("/form")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public StudentServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/form.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String username = request.getParameter("name");
        String school = request.getParameter("school");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
        int code = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("code"));
        int mobile = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobile"));
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        Date dob = Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("dob"));
        
        
        Student student = new Student(code, username, school ,age, email, mobile, dob);
        
        StudentDAO.insertStudent(student);
        
        response.sendRedirect("data.jsp");
        
        
        
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

I have imported various jar files like Jakarta.persistence-api and jakarta.transition-api among many others.
I have also restarted my eclipse ide but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Is your project targeting a server that would provide them? That's how you're supposed to do this, and you were shown those options when creating the project.

Comment: You are looking for `jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:jar:6.0.0` or jars to that effect :)